# intel NUC 12 AMT limits NIC to 100mbit

Tags: networking, intel-amt, vpro

I have some 12th NUCs here, and I would like to enable remote management. If I set them up to do DHCP for the AMT, it works, but the management interface disappears as soon as the OS comes up and accesses the NIC. When I assign it a fixed IP address, it does work, but the link on the switch is stuck at 100mbit (the switch is a 8 port ubiquiti unifi desktop switch). Is there anything I can do there?

.rm

Comment: After the NUC is up, does `http://<IP>:16992/` give access? Is the link speed/duplex maybe forced in the NIC settings?

Comment: yes, if ii assign a fixed ip, the os does dhcp, i can get the AMT interface on $fixed_ip:16992, and i can access the os vua ssh on $dhcp_ip:22 .... but in this case, the link stays at 100mbit. if i configure AMT to use DHCP, it is accessible until the OS accesses the nic, then link switches to 1gbit, but AMT is no longer accessible. OS is.